# I want to update an related Account Country field when a new Contact is Created with country field value,

Tags: apex, trigger, account, contact

I am new to Salesforce.

I am trying to update the Account country field, when a new Contact is inserted or update related to it. I understand this, but the condition is:

- "if first Contact created with country name ='India', it should update the account Country field with 'India',
- when the second Contact is created with country name 'USA', it should not update Account Field with 'USA'; it should have the previous value 'India',
- but when a third Contact is created with country field name 'USA', it should update Account Field with 'USA'.
- when fourth contact is created with country field name 'India', it should not change the Account field value as 'India', it should be 'USA' as the count for both will be same.
- but when fifth contact is created with country field name 'India' it should update account field value as 'India' as 'India' count will more than 'USA'."

I have to do this for at least 10 countries. I'm getting confused on how to do it. Please can you help me with this.

Thank you.

I have developed the following:

```java
public static Integer countIn = 0;
public static Integer countUs = 0;
public static String finalCount;

   
public static void CountryMethodCount(){
    //   Set<Id> setIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Contact> newMapCon = new Map<Id,Contact>();
    
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
            if(con.Contact_Countrys__c != null){
                // setIds.add(con.AccountId);
                newMapCon.put(con.AccountId, con);
            } 
        }        
    }
    
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        for(Contact con : Trigger.old){
            if(con.Contact_Countrys__c != null){
                // setIds.add(con.AccountId);
                newMapCon.put(con.AccountId, con);
            } 
        }
    }
    
    List<Contact> newConIn = [SELECT Id,Contact_Countrys__c FROM Contact WHERE Contact_Countrys__c = 'India' AND AccountId IN:newMapCon.keySet()];
    
    if(newConIn.size() != null){
        countIn =  newConIn.size();  
    }
    
    List<Contact> newConUs = [SELECT Id,Contact_Countrys__c FROM Contact WHERE Contact_Countrys__c = 'USA' AND AccountId IN:newMapCon.keySet()];
    
    if(newConUs.size() != null){
        countUs =  newConUs.size();  
    }
    System.debug('India ' + countIn + 'USA '+ countUs);
    
    if(countIn > countUs){
        finalCount = 'India';
    }
    else if(countIn < countUs){
        finalCount = 'USA';
    }
    System.debug('Final ' + finalCount);
    
    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id,Contact_Country_c__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN:newMapCon.keySet()];
    List<Account> newListm = new List<Account>();
    
    for(Account acc : accList){
        Contact co = newMapCon.get(acc.Id);
        if(finalCount != NULL && acc.Id == co.AccountId){
            acc.Contact_Country_c__c = finalCount;
            newListm.add(acc);
        }
    }   
    if(newListm != NULL && !newListm.isEmpty()){
        update newListm;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This seems like something that Aggregate Functions (combined with GROUP BY) in a query can do. This site works best when you show us what you've tried so far (we're not a free coding service) and can point to a specific spot that you're having trouble with. Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: If I understand correctly, You want the Country field on Account be updated with the Country added most number of times to the related contacts. A simple way to figure out is to query the count of contacts related to the account and GROUP BY the Country and sort in descending order of Count of contacts. This will give you how many contacts are associated with each country. Once  you solve for one Account, then bulkification should be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to maintain counts for individual countries would work, but it is cumbersome (and using one query per country is wasteful) and there is a better way to go about this.

The recurring themes you'll find in deleoping for the Salesforce platform are:

- Work on collections of records (lists, sets, or maps) instead of on individual records
- Keep the number of queries you use as low as possible

Looping over trigger context variables (e.g. `trigger.new`, `trigger.old`, `trigger.newMap`, `trigger.oldMap`) to gather Ids to use in your queries is precicely what you want to be doing. Good job on picking that habit up early!

Figuring out the most represented country in each Account's contacts can be handled by a single query (plus some processing in Apex) if you add the `GROUP BY` clause.

Using `GROUP BY` has some consequences:

- All of the fields in the `SELECT` clause need to either appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, or be used in an Aggregate Function like `COUNT()`
- The result of the query will be a `List<AggregateResult>`, which is slightly harder to use than a list of a specific SObject

but using that means we don't need to do as much work in Apex.

In your case, you'd be looking to group contacts first by their AccountId, and then by their Country. You would also COUNT() how many contacts exist for each grouping. Your query should end up looking something like this

```
[SELECT COUNT(Id) numberOfRecords, AccountId, Contact_Countrys__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :newMapCon.keySet() GROUP BY AccountId, Contact_Countrys__c];
```

That query will end up giving you results like

| AccountId | Contact_Countrys__c | numberOfRecords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acctId 1 | India | 5 |
| acctId 1 | USA | 2 |
| acctId 1 | Germany | 1 |
| acctId 2 | USA | 4 |
| acctId 3 | India | 2 |
| acctId 3 | Germany | 7 |

Normally, there's no real way to predict what order the results for each account will be in. If you use `ORDER BY` though, you can guarantee things will be in a specific order. You just need to be careful in how you order (so that you don't end up making your job harder). `ORDER BY AccountId, COUNT(Id) DESC` should do.

With an ordered list, the rest of your work should become easy. You won't need to explicitly keep track of the maximum count for each given AccountId because the maximum count will always be the first row you encounter for any given AccountId.

That leads very nicely into the final point here. If you have the Id of an SObject, you can update that record without needing to perform a query. You can use the SObject constructor to set the record Id.

Putting that all together, that means that (gathering account ids for your query aside) your logic can become quite short and elegant.

```
// This logic could be shortened a bit more, but I'm choosing to keep some things
//   on separate lines for instructive purposes
Map<Id, Account> accountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>();

for(AggregateResult ar :[<your grouped, ordered query here>]){
    // When working with an AggregateResult, we need to use .get() to retrieve individual
    //   fields.
    // .get() returns an Object, and we need to explicitly type-cast it to make it useful
    Id currentAccountId = (Id)ar.get('AccountId');
    String country = (String)ar.get('Contact_Countrys__c');
    // If you didn't give an alias to COUNT(Id), you would access the result with
    //   'expr0' instead
    Integer count = (Integer)ar.get('numberOfRecords');

    // If this accountId already exists in the map, then we know this is not the first
    //   time we've encountered this Id (and thanks to the ORDER BY, that it is also not
    //   the most represented country).
    // We can ignore this record and continue on to the next one
    if(accountsMap.containsKey(currentAccountId)){
        continue;
    }

    // If we make it to this point, this is the first time we've seen this account id
    accountsMap.put(currentAccountId, new Account(Id = currentAccountId, Contact_Country_c__c = country));
}

// There is basically never a need to check to see if a collection is empty or not before
//   performing DML.
// Salesforce does that sanity check for us (and doesn't count the DML against us for
//   the transaction if it is empty)
update accountsMap.values();
```